# Trigonometric Functions for reference angle

Tags: trigonometry

What is the formula or algorithm to find the sine and cosine given only the angle with the hypotenuse of 1.
For example is the angle 290 degrees with the reference angle of 70 degrees, how to find the sine and cosine of it?

[image: Sine and cosine reference angles diagram]

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a very specific way to calculate the sine or cosine of a general angle. There are, however, ways to approximate them. One involves the Maclaurin series of sine and cosine, which are:

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...\\
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$

(Just note to convert angles to radians before plugging into the above formula)